# How to find a mean between these 2 numbers in 1 column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to find a mean between these 2 numbers in 1 column and update column `built_up` with mean value? And also ignore the number that not in range.

```
  built_up
0 1498-1602
1 1022-1187
2 1713-1970
3 2305-3396
4 1420
5 -
```

Here is my data - https://gist.github.com/datomnurdin/21b028b8ed213aacbe4ba4b71ccfe384

I already removed `From` and `sq. ft.` using this

```
df['built_up'] = df['built_up'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('From ').rstrip(' sq. ft.'))
```

Comment: I recommend you give this question and its answers a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @PaulH just fixed it. tq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: For you real data, you should use `str.findall` as follows

```
df['b_median'] = [np.median(pd.to_numeric(x if bool(x) else np.nan, errors='coerce')) 
                         for x in df['built_up'].str.findall('\d+')]
```

---

**Original**:

Your real data have some unbalanced strings, try `strip` before call `map` with `np.median` and `pd.to_numeric`

```
s = (df['built_up'].map(lambda x: 
                        np.median(pd.to_numeric(x.strip('- ').split('-'), errors='coerce'))))

Out[356]:
0    1550.0
1    1104.5
2    1841.5
3    2850.5
4    1420.0
5       NaN
Name: built_up, dtype: float64
```

---

**Method 2**: On processing strings in pandas cell, list comprehension is faster

```
df['b_median'] = [np.mean(pd.to_numeric(x.strip('- ').split('-'), errors='coerce')) 
                       for x in df.built_up]

Out[354]:
    built_up  b_median
0  1498-1602    1550.0
1  1022-1187    1104.5
2  1713-1970    1841.5
3  2305-3396    2850.5
4       1420    1420.0
5          -       NaN
```

Comment: you can refer my data here, https://gist.github.com/datomnurdin/21b028b8ed213aacbe4ba4b71ccfe384

Comment: @MohammadNurdin: I added a solution for your real data

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two values you can use `mean` :

```
df['built_up'].str.split('-', expand=True).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    1550.0
1    1104.5
2    1841.5
3    2850.5
4    1420.0
5       NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I got NaN instead values.

Comment: @MohammadNurdin With `median`?

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: ```.fillna(0).astype(float)```

Comment: @MohammadNurdin You have some problems in you data that we cannot reproduce.

Comment: you can refer my data here, https://gist.github.com/datomnurdin/21b028b8ed213aacbe4ba4b71ccfe384

Comment: @MohammadNurdin I edited my answer. We cannot clean your data.